# java for loop does not update variable

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

```
public CarDealerShip() {
    cars = new Car[80];
    listSize=0;
}
public void addNewCar (String model, int year, int price, String color) {
    m = model;
    y = year;
    p = price;
    c = color;
    cars [listSize] = new NewCar (m,y,p,c);
    listSize++;
}
public void addUsedCar (String model, int year, int price, boolean rusty) {
    m = model;
    y = year;
    p = price;
    r = rusty;
    cars [listSize] = new UsedCar(m,y,p,r);
    listSize++;
}
public String printReport() {
    String list="";
    if (cars.length==listSize)
        for (int i =0; i <= listSize; i++)
            list+=cars[i].toString()+"\n";
    return list;
}
```

In the method `printReport`, the for loop is suppose to update the variable list but does nothing at all. It been a while since i use Java again so any help is appreciated.

Comment: People of StackOverflow! A downvote is made more constructive when accompanied by an explanation.

Comment: (cars.length==listSize -1) might solve your problem.

Comment: @aa_oo Won't `cars.length` always equal `80`, if declared `cars = new Car[80]` ?

Comment: yes, but the listSize will be one less than cars.length AT MAX

Answer (score 1):

Since `0 <= 0`, the `for` loop will iterate once even if `listSize==0` (even if `cars[0]` is not defined).

So if `printReport` "does nothing at all" (including throwing an exception), the most likely cause is that the expression in the `if` statement evaluates to `false`.

This might happen if you haven't added 80 cars to `cars` when you try calling `printReport`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object of the class CarDealerShip, the variable listSize gets a value of 0 while the 'cars' array is 80 elements long.
So basically this IF fails:
if (cars.length==listSize).
Hence, the for loop is never entered.
This is all that can be said from the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line :

```
if (cars.length==listSize)
```

Because cars is a array whose length is 80 and  the variable listSize gets a value of 0 at the time of creating this class . So for loop is not executed .